# Index out of range Python NUmerical Iteration

Tags: python, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I am a beginner in Python . While running the following code.

```
from array import *  
x=[]  
x[0]=.232  
for i in range(25):   
x[i+1]=1/[i+1]-5*x[i] 
end
```

I get an error:

> x[0]=.232 IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Can someone help me sort this out

Comment: The current code in this question cannot run as is, please edit your question so that it will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x=[] makes an empty list so you can't call x[0], so make a list of 26 elements(you need all total 26 elements) all equal to zero for convenience,

```
 x=[0.0]*26
```

or

```
x=[0.0 for i in range(26)]
```

again `[i+1]` denotes a list and you cant do calculation with that make (i+1). also `1/(i+1)` gives integer division make 1.0/(i+1)
`end` is not a valid python function here, dont use it indente the next line under the for loop. final programme,

```
x=[0.0]*26  
x[0]=.232  
for i in range(25):   
    x[i+1]=1.0/(i+1)-5*x[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has more errors, but in this particular case you are trying to access the first position (`x[0]`) of an empty array (**declared as `x=[]`**)

The same error appears in the loop (**`x[i+1]` is index out of range since the array is empty**) and you have a syntax error, `end` is not a python keyword. Finally, the body of the loop should be indented.